# python daemon threads print doesn't show in deamon tools log until program terminate

Tags: python, daemon

I have a python program working fine. After I move it to use djb daemon tools to start it, the print out message in the daemon threads doesn't show until I stop the program. I am using python 2.6, and the python program is running on Centos. Has anyone experienced that? How to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried adding a flush? (import sys
sys.stdout.flush())

Comment: do you mean every time print, use flush? Currently I solve that by use logging, but I want to know whether there is a way that I can just use print for this.